# Showing the Boundedness of a Function $ f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

To show that the function $(f)$ is bounded, we need to find an upper bound $(M)$ such that:

$(|f(x)| \leq M)$, for all $(x \in \mathbb{R}^2)$.

Let's consider the case when $((x, y)^t \neq (0, 0)^t)$. In this case, we have:

$f(x) = \dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$

To find an upper bound for $(f(x))$, we can maximize the denominator and minimize the numerator.

The denominator $(x^2+y^4)$ is always positive for any real numbers $(x)$ and $(y)$ since both terms are squared. Hence, we can assume that the denominator is always positive.

To minimize the numerator $(xy^2)$, we can choose the absolute smallest value for $(y^2)$, which is $0$. This means that the numerator is also $0$.

Thus, we have $(f(x) = 0)$ for all $((x, y)^t \neq (0, 0)^t)$.

For the case when $((x, y)^t = (0, 0)^t)$, we have:

$[f(0, 0) = 0]$

In both cases, (f(x)) is always equal to $0$.

Since $(|f(x)| = |0| = 0)$ for all $(x \in \mathbb{R}^2)$, we can choose $(M = 0)$ as an upper bound.

Therefore, the function $f$ is bounded with $(|f(x)| \leq 0)$ for all $(x \in \mathbb{R}^2)$.

I'm pretty much sure, that my solution is not correct but after checking it several times, I can't find any problems. I would really appreciate any kind of your help.

Comment: right, I have edited the question

Comment: Use the inequality $$2|ab|\le a^2+b^2. $$

Comment: What's up with the overuse of parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use polar coordinates. Call $w = y^2$ and write $(x, w) = (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta))$. Then we have that:
$$
   | f(x, w) | = \left| \frac{r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta}{r^2} \right|= |\cos \theta \sin \theta|
$$
which is bounded.

Comment: Use geometric mean $\le$ arithmetic mean for positive quantities |x| and $y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\;\dfrac12\left(|x|-y^2\right)^2\geqslant0\;,\;$ it results that

$|f(x,\!y)|=\left|\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2\!+\!y^4}\right|=\dfrac{|x|y^2}{x^2\!+\!y^4}\leqslant\dfrac{|x|y^2\!+\!\frac12\left(|x|\!-\!y^2\right)^2}{x^2\!+\!y^4}=\dfrac12.$

Consequently, an upper bound of the function $\,|f(x,y)|\,$ is $\,M=\dfrac12\,.$

Actually, $M=\dfrac12\;$ and $\;-M=-\dfrac12\;$ are respectively the maximum and the minimum value of the function $\,f(x,y)\,,\;$ indeed ,

for $\,x=y^2\neq0\;,\;\;$ $f(x,y)=\dfrac{y^2\!\cdot\!y^2}{y^4+y^4}=\dfrac{y^4}{2y^4}=\dfrac12\;\;,$

for $\,x=-y^2\neq0\;,\;\;$ $f(x,y)=\dfrac{-y^2\!\cdot\!y^2}{y^4+y^4}=\dfrac{-y^4}{2y^4}=-\dfrac12\;.$